# Royal Television Society payment problem

Tags: payment-processor

I am trying to register for the RTS Virtual Careers Fair 2021, but no matter what card I try, I keep getting a denial message. Can you please help? I am accessing the payment from this page, empowered by you https://rts.org.uk/civicrm/event/register?id=446&reset=1

Thanks.

Kind regards,
Gergana Georgieva

Comment: Hi Gergana, we've checked all of the processes running and cant see any issues at the moment. Perhaps if you could email me directly with specific issues we can help get this resolved (note there have been over 100 registrations in the last couple of days without issue). Parvez at vedaconsulting dot co dot uk

Answer (score 1):

We are the support providers for the Royal Television Society, we'll take a look and come back to you.